# kurento-media-server Segmentation fault

Tags: kurento

I am using Kurento Media Server (6.4.0) and kurento-room.

---

Environment:

```
server:
os........: ubuntu14.04

cpu.......: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2680 v3 @ 2.50GHz, 4core
memory....: 8G

clients:

Several MacBook Chrome browsers.
```

---

When we run with several rooms, Kurento media server crashes.

---

logs:

> Warning: Still 1 object/s alive
>
> (kurento-media-server:1333): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL)
>   pointer instance
>
> (kurento-media-server:1333): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **:
>   g_signal_emit_valist: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)'
>   failed
>
> ** (kurento-media-server:1333): CRITICAL *: gst_video_frame_map_id: assertion 'info->width <= meta->width' failed
>
> ......................
>
> - (kurento-media-server:1701): CRITICAL **: gst_video_frame_map_id: assertion 'info->width <= meta->width' failed
>
> [31;1mSegmentation fault[0m (thread [33;1m140007894537984[0m, pid
>
> [33;1m1701[0m)
>
> Stack trace:
>
> [34;1m[g_type_check_instance_cast][0m
>
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0[32;1m:0x34984[0m
>
> [34;1m[check_if_flow_media][0m
>
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkmsgstcommons.so.6[32;1m:0x1A9A0[0m
>
> [34;1m[gst_structure_fixate][0m
>
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstreamer-1.5.so.0[32;1m:0x99E44[0m
>
> [34;1m[g_test_get_filename][0m
>
> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0[32;1m:0x70965[0m
>
> [34;1m[start_thread][0m
>
> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0[32;1m:0x8182[0m
>
> [34;1m[clone][0m
>
> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6[32;1m:0xFA47D[0m
>
> \00

---

Thanks! And sorry for the long description :)

Comment: i had check the kms version

webrtc@xxx:~$ kurento-media-server -v
Version: 6.4.0
Found modules:
Module: 'core' version '6.4.0'
Module: 'elements' version '6.4.0'
Module: 'filters' version '6.4.0'
Module: 'pointerdetector' version '6.4.0'
webrtc@xxx:~$

Comment: What server are you using (specs) and how many rooms? You'll need to monitor the statistics when the crash happens.